# how order of tables in cross join affect performance

Tags: join, clickhouse

I have 2 tables `A` and `B`, both are `MergeTree` with 8192 `index_granularity`. 
When I apply `cross join` to 2 tables. In general, query likes

```
select
    count(*)
from
(select * from A where ... )
cross join
(select * from B where ...)
where ...;
```

- Original table: `A` has `314307856` records, `B` has `909470`.
- Filter out: `A` has `6599` records, `B` has `14860`. (both filter are very fast despite of significant record difference)

I notice a huge gap of performance when switching order of `A` and `B` in query.

- When `A cross join B`: `1 rows in set. Elapsed: 12.242 sec. Processed 26.72 million rows`
- When `B cross join A`: `1 rows in set. Elapsed: 45.584 sec. Processed 26.72 million rows`

Both order has `pipeline`

```
CreatingSets
 Lazy
 Expression
  Expression
   ParallelAggregating
    Expression × (num_parts)
     Filter
      Expression
       Expression
        Expression
         Filter
          MergeTreeThread
```

Sometime, `B cross join A` has

```
CreatingSets
 Lazy
 Expression
  Expression
   Aggregating
    Concat
     Expression
      Filter
       Expression
        Limit
         Expression
          Union
           Limit × 7
            Expression
             Filter
              MergeTreeThread
```

--> I notice that `clickhouse-server` will burst out my memory very fast with this pipeline.

As I know, with `join` query, `clickhouse` will execute the execution in the right first, put it in memory then executes the left next. In my case, both filter-out `A` and `B` are definitely fit in memory.

My questions are:

- Why do 2 queries have a huge difference performance? How order of 2 tables affect performance of query? Some advice when choosing order.
- Can pipeline be different with a same query in multiple executions?

Update 1:
More detail about my query

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
    FROM 
    (
          SELECT 
            ...
        FROM B 
        WHERE (((day >= '2018-08-15') AND (day <= '2018-08-16')) AND ((timestamp >= 1534310226442) AND (timestamp <= 1534399065648))) AND (log_time <= 1534316318187)
    ) 
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT 
            ...
        FROM A
        WHERE (((day >= '2018-08-14') AND (day <= '2018-08-16')) AND ((timestamp >= 1534223826442) AND (timestamp <= 1534399065648))) AND (log_time <= 1534316318187) AND match(..., '...') 
    ) 
    WHERE position(..., ...) > 1
```

Comment: Please show us what that `WHERE` clause is doing, because you may not really be doing a cross join.

Comment: Hi. Start by reading a query optimization/implementation chapter of a relational database textbook. Please also read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

1. At the moment ClickHouse do not have a cost-based optimizer to automatically swap tables if it's more favourable way to achieve the same result. There are many possible reasons why this difference exists in the first place, like better processor cache utilization or doing extra work before throwing it away because of WHERE. Performance introspection features are currently in the process of being merged into ClickHouse master and will be available in coming releases, for now digging deeper is mostly limited to normal linux toolset like perf/strace/dstat/etc. As of advice, you did absolutely the right thing by measuring what works best for exactly your case, don't blindly trust anyone's advice.
2. ClickHouse is more or less deterministic, so it shouldn't change with fixed query. Can you provide a way to reproduce this?